# cannot install at all (ubuntu 12.04 amd64)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've got a VM running Ubuntu 12.04.1 x86 on my laptop, and my desktop is running 12.04 amd64.

Installation on the VM went smooth.
No way of getting ROS Fuerte to install on the desktop though.

I updated the sources as per the installation tutorial, but when I get to the actual installation there are all sorts of unmet dependencies.

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1346187746~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1346209883~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1346186954~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-filters (= 1.6.0-s1346190801~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1346196768~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.14-s1346200794~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.14-s1346193234~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.4-s1346232876~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1346187964~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1346197152~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1346200453~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1346212230~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.4-s1346233129~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1346191138~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1346199496~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1346186808~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1346255820~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1346187257~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bond-core (= 1.6.3-s1346187671~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding (= 0.1.7-s1346191935~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1346192005~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1346191674~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1346186749~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1346197089~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1346208690~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.4.2-s1346186665~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.2-s1346415886~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1346189334~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1346188771~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1346186848~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-pluginlib (= 1.8.0-s1346186500~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1346187100~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1346257099~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1346210657~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.4-s1346190893~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1346230244~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common (= 1.8.0-s1346190692~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1346186564~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1346191272~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I didn't do anything different on this machine, than I did on the VM.
So I can't understand where does all of this come from.
I hope somebody can help me.

here are the sources

```
 sudo apt-get update
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release                                    
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US   
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources          
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main TranslationIndex                      
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages               
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages             
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages     
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

as far as I can see, all the ROS sources are there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43187/cannot-install-at-all-(ubuntu-12.04-amd64)/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2012-09-06**:
Somehow I can't see my own answer.
Anyway: solution is to get rid of libboost 1.48.
ROS requires 1.46 and it can't be installed onto 1.48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved: I was using libboost 1.48.

ROS requires (hardwired dependencies) libboost 1.46.
So as apt-get was unable to resolve the conflict, it said it had unmet dependencies.

Solution: remove all 1.48 libboost packages, install ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on 2013-05-15**:
Why are groovy and hydro debians for Ubuntu 12.4 not compiled against boost 1.48? Ubuntu 12.4 comes both with boost 1.46 & 1.48, but 1.46 has some problems with c++11